# How to loop over string data type & iterate over it using javascript for displaying the data as list item in html?

Tags: javascript, html

I am learning JS by self kindly assist here I am trying to  iterate over the below data which is of type string & want to display it in  a html file as list items ,  I am able to get the whole data displayed the problem i am facing is  this data I need to display  as list items but with the current code it is coming all in a single list item

**JS code below**

```js
data = Host Name: COMPUTERHOPE
OS Name: Microsoft Windows 10 Pro
OS Version: 10.0 .10586 N / A Build 10586
OS Manufacturer: Microsoft Corporation
OS Configuration: Standalone Workstation
OS Build Type: Multiprocessor Free
Registered Owner: Computerhope
Registered Organization: Computer Hope
Product ID: 00000 - 00000 - 00000 - AAAAA
Original Install Date: 12 / 17 / 2015, 7: 09: 50 PM
System Boot Time: 3 / 28 / 2016, 6: 57: 39 AM
System Manufacturer: Dell Inc.
System Model: XPS 8300
System Type: x64 - based PC
Processor(s): 1 Processor(s) Installed.
  [01]: Intel64 Family 6 Model 42 Stepping 7 Genuine Intel~3401 Mhz
BIOS Version: Dell Inc.A06, 10 / 17 / 2011
Windows Directory: C: \WINDOWS
System Directory: C: \WINDOWS\ system32
Boot Device: \Device\ HarddiskVolume1
System Locale: en - us;
English(United States)
Input Locale: en - us;
English(United States)
Time Zone: (UTC - 07: 00) Mountain Time(US & Canada)
Total Physical Memory: 8, 174 MB
Available Physical Memory: 2, 955 MB
Virtual Memory: Max Size: 16, 366 MB
Virtual Memory: Available: 6, 455 MB
Virtual Memory: In Use: 9, 911 MB
Page File Location(s): C: \pagefile.sys
Domain: WORKGROUP
Logon Server: \\MicrosoftAccount
Hotfix(s): 10 Hotfix(s) Installed.
  [01]: KB3116900[02]: KB3124200[03]: KB3124262[04]: KB3124263[05]: KB3135173[06]: KB3139907[07]: KB3140741[08]: KB3140743[09]: KB3140768[10]: KB3144756
Network Card(s): 2 NIC(s) Installed.
  [01]: DW1501 Wireless - N WLAN Half - Mini Card
Connection Name: Wi - Fi
Status: Media disconnected[02]: Broadcom NetLink(TM) Gigabit Ethernet
Connection Name: Ethernet
DHCP Enabled: Yes
DHCP Server: 192.168 .1 .1
IP address(es)[01]: 192.168 .1 .52[02]: fe00::b0b0: 0000: 0000: 0000
Hyper - V Requirements: VM Monitor Mode Extensions: Yes
Virtualization Enabled In Firmware: Yes
Second Level Address Translation: Yes
Data Execution Prevention Available: Yes

 document.getElementById("one").innerText = data  # need assistance here
```

**Html code below**

```html
<ol>
  <li id="one"></li>
</ol>
```

Comment: Since you're trying to show data from a string in different list items, you need an identifier to [split the string](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) so you can iterate over the results.

Comment: @Jordy i am new to js if possible can kindly ping an example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are looking for something like this:

```
data.split("\n").forEach(e => { // split data string at line terminator (\n)
  const li = document.createElement("li"); // create entry
  li.innerText = e; // set text to row data
  list.appendChild(li); // append list item node to list
});
```

See a small example below.

```js
const data = `Host Name: COMPUTERHOPE\nOS Name: Microsoft Windows 10 Pro\nOS Version: 10.0 .10586 N / A Build 10586\nOS Manufacturer: Microsoft Corporation\nOS Configuration: Standalone Workstation\nOS Build Type: Multiprocessor Free\nRegistered Owner: Computerhope\nRegistered Organization: Computer Hope\nProduct ID: 00000 - 00000 - 00000 - AAAAA\nOriginal Install Date: 12 / 17 / 2015, 7: 09: 50 PM\nSystem Boot Time: 3 / 28 / 2016, 6: 57: 39 AM\nSystem Manufacturer: Dell Inc.\nSystem Model: XPS 8300\nSystem Type: x64 - based PC\nProcessor(s): 1 Processor(s) Installed.\n  [01]: Intel64 Family 6 Model 42 Stepping 7 Genuine Intel~3401 Mhz\nBIOS Version: Dell Inc.A06, 10 / 17 / 2011\nWindows Directory: C: WINDOWS\nSystem Directory: C: WINDOWS system32\nBoot Device: Device HarddiskVolume1\nSystem Locale: en - us;\nEnglish(United States)\nInput Locale: en - us;\nEnglish(United States)\nTime Zone: (UTC - 07: 00) Mountain Time(US & Canada)\nTotal Physical Memory: 8, 174 MB\nAvailable Physical Memory: 2, 955 MB\nVirtual Memory: Max Size: 16, 366 MB\nVirtual Memory: Available: 6, 455 MB\nVirtual Memory: In Use: 9, 911 MB\nPage File Location(s): C: pagefile.sys\nDomain: WORKGROUP\nLogon Server: \\MicrosoftAccount\nHotfix(s): 10 Hotfix(s) Installed.\n  [01]: KB3116900[02]: KB3124200[03]: KB3124262[04]: KB3124263[05]: KB3135173[06]: KB3139907[07]: KB3140741[08]: KB3140743[09]: KB3140768[10]: KB3144756\nNetwork Card(s): 2 NIC(s) Installed.\n  [01]: DW1501 Wireless - N WLAN Half - Mini Card\nConnection Name: Wi - Fi\nStatus: Media disconnected[02]: Broadcom NetLink(TM) Gigabit Ethernet\nConnection Name: Ethernet\nDHCP Enabled: Yes\nDHCP Server: 192.168 .1 .1\nIP address(es)[01]: 192.168 .1 .52[02]: fe00::b0b0: 0000: 0000: 0000\nHyper - V Requirements: VM Monitor Mode Extensions: Yes\nVirtualization Enabled In Firmware: Yes\nSecond Level Address Translation: Yes\nData Execution Prevention Available: Yes";`;

data.split("\n").forEach(e => {
  const li = document.createElement("li");
  li.innerText = e;
  list.appendChild(li);
});
```

```html
<ul id="list"></ul>
```